# Printing just the value in groovy loop

Tags: loops, groovy

Code in the controller

```
    def sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance ( dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver )
    String[] allUser = sql.rows("select user_id from users")
    allUser.each()
    {
        print "${it}"
    }
```

The output in the console

```
{user_id=9}
{user_id=10}
{user_id=11}
{user_id=12}
{user_id=13}
{user_id=14}
```

How do I print it in such a way that it will display just the value? Example:

```
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes it a bit more intricate than it needs to be.  `Sql.rows()` will return a list of [`GroovyRowResult`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/GroovyRowResult.html) objects, which make it easy to retrieve the fields;  you have an implicit cast to `String[]`, based on your variable declaration.  You can change it as follows:

```
def allUser = sql.rows("select user_id from users")
```

or, if you prefer,

```
List allUser = sql.rows("select user_id from users")
```

Then you can print the userid's like so:

```
allUser.each {
    println it["user_id"]
}
```

Comment: Wow this is really helpful and useful if I need to add more selection in my SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
   String userid = "${it}".substring(0, "${it}".length()-1);
   String[] test = userid.split("=")
```